# Why does CachePut not work in this example?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache, spring-scheduled

I am playing around with the Spring framework and I would like to get my name returned from the cache. After 5 seconds I will update the cache and I hope to receive a new name.... unfortunately this is not working.... why?

```
@Component
public class Test {

    public String name = "peter";

    @Cacheable(value = "numCache")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    @CachePut(value = "numCache")
    public String setName() {
        this.name = "piet";
        return name;
    }


}

@Component
public class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    Test test = new Test();

    while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(test.getName());
    }

}


}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, yeah I did.. I will update my example

Comment: You are using `new` to create a `Test` instance. You need to autowire it.

Comment: YES!!! Now it is working.... thanks Hassan for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `Test` yourself with `new`, you are not autowiring it. I would try like this:

```
@Component
public class Test {

    public String name = "peter";

    @Cacheable(value = "numCache")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    @CachePut(value = "numCache")
    public String setName() {
        this.name = "piet";
        return name;
    }


}

@Component
public class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired private Test test;

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(test.getName());
        }
    }
}
```